# Fill select row above and below index value

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, dplyr, fill

Ran into an issue while working in R
I have a variable (X) in data frame (df) which looks like this

```
df$X
NA
12345
NA
NA
32409
NA
NA
NA
NA
NA
04598
NA
NA
NA
```

I need to do the following:

Where X is not NA, replace:
- the previous row in X with the value
- fill in the remainder of the rows until the next value is reached

Ultimately, it needs to look like this

```
df$X
12345
12345
12345
32409
32409
32409
32409
32409
32409
04598
04598
04598
04598
04598
```

I tried using a for loop to accomplish the first part (filling in the previous row) but can't seem to get this to work

```
for (x in df$X) {

x = df$X[x]  
y = x -1  
df$X[y] <-  ifelse(!is.na(x), x, NA)

}
```

Your help much appreciated!

Comment: Your question is not clear. What you want to do is not fully understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach with `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(X = if_else(is.na(X), lead(X), X)) %>%
  tidyr::fill(X)
```